# Using an OPC-478 programming cable for CI-V

Tags: connectors, icom, audio-interface, computer-control

I have an [clone of] an Icom OPC-478 programming cable for my IC-208H. I thought I read that I can use that same cable to do CI-V with my IC-706 if I can find an 1/8" mono (male) to 1/8" stereo (female) adapter.

If I understood correctly, the OPC-478 has a TRS with audio on T, data on R and ground on S, whereas CI-V is just a TS with data on T and ground on S.  Do I have it right?

Comment: I couldn't find my adapter, so I can't answer my exact question, but I did try an experiment.  I had also read that you can use that cable if you make a TRS->RTS adapter (1/8" female with a 1/8" male, T wired to R and R wired to T) and can confirm that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally obtained one of the described adapters, and I can confirm that yes, it does indeed work fine.